# Selenide IntelliJ IDEA - inserting text from current clipboarrd into the Login form instead of @

Tags: intellij-idea, selenide

I have a wierd problem:
Our Selenide automat keep inserting the text, that is currently in my clipboard into the login form, that use email.
The text is inserted instead of @:

[image: EXAMPLE]

The code is as follow:

```
B2CLogin login = new B2CLogin();
login.userCanLogIn();
```

*B2CLogin include:*

```
public class B2CLogin {
@Test
public void userCanLogIn() {
    DevBasicAuthorization auth = new DevBasicAuthorization();
    auth.userCanAuthorization();
    //open login popup
    $("[data-test-id='Navigation-item-signIn']").click();
    //choose LogIn
    $("[data-test-id='signInForm_sign_in_tab']").click();
    //fill login
    $("[id='username']").setValue(b2cdevuser);
    //fill password
    $("[id='password']").setValue(b2cdevpass);
    //click LogIn button
    $("[data-test-id='signInForm_submitButton']").click();
    //Profile button should be visible
    $("[id='Navigation-item-profile-desktop']").waitUntil(Condition.visible, 6000);
}
```

*Variables:*

```
//b2c dev account
public static String b2cdevuser = "CZtestB2B@gmail.com";
public static String b2cdevpass = "test1234";
```

Do anyone know hoe to solve this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to use .append() insted of setValue()